# Proxy http upload to another server

Tags: http, file-upload

My application consists of a UI web server and an application web server, both of them communicates through a message bus.

now I want to let user upload a file through their web browser, the problem is, user's browser is connecting UI web server, but I want to the file is finally uploaded to application web server.

How can I do this? Can I redirect all http upload requests to application server? Is there any example I can follow? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, by just changing the POST location of the `<form`'s `action=` attribute to the script you want to accept the file on the appropriate url location.  The location you post to must be accessible to the user to be able to POST to.

The other option is to post it to your UI web server, and from your UI web server, send it to the application web server.

e.g.

`<form action="http://other-server.example.com" method="POST">`

See also:

- [HTML Form POST Cross Domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497609/html-form-post-cross-domain)
- [Cross Domain Form POSTing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423682/cross-domain-form-posting)
- [Send cross domain HTTP Post with HTML forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152363/send-cross-domain-http-post-with-html-forms)

Comment: unfortunately the application is invisible to user.

Comment: @zx_wing, then you have to post it across from your public site to your private site. As no one can post it directly to a private site because it's private of course.